# split a string in a column when it encounters date

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe column with a string of below patterns:

```
Col A

ABC29SEP2286AB

PQRST29SEP22FUN
```

I want to split the string such that I get the date to act as a separator, so desired output would be:

```
ColA ColB ColC

ABC 29SEP22 86AB

PQRST 29SEP22 FUN
```

Can you please advise how i can use the date part to act as the trigger for splitting the string.
The date part will always have 7 characters ddmmmyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df[["ColA", "ColB", "ColC"]] = df["ColA"].str.extract(r'([A-Z]+)(\d{2}[A-Z]{3})(.*)', expand=True)
```

Check this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VpEIwA/1) to see the pattern working against your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), splitting on the date part, putting a capturing group around it so that we retain the date in the output:

```py
df[['Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C']] = df['Col A'].str.split(r'(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2})', expand=True, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   Col A    Col B Col C
0    ABC  29SEP22  86AB
1  PQRST  29SEP22   FUN
```

Note that for pandas versions prior to `1.4.0` you don't need the `regex=True` parameter to `split`.

Note also that - dependent on your data - you may need to use

```
(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)
```

in place of `[A-Z]{3}`